# REST API Getting 401 UnAuthorized

Tags: here-api

I am using .NET Core Web API to make call and getting back
401, unauthorized ? I am using a REST API key.

```
var ApiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        
var _Http = new HttpClient();
var response = await _Http.GetAsync($"https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q={address},{city},{state},{postalCode},{country}&apikey={ApiKey}");
```

What am I missing ?

I am getting the key from the following section

[image]

Comment: 401 Unauthorized means your api key is not valid.

Comment: well i understand that, but it does not help fix the problem. I have double checked key and it  is correct.. Which section of

Comment: Are you by any chance using App ID instead of API key?

Comment: No, i am using API Key which is much longer, so no mistake there

Comment: Just wanted to Update. I created new Key and it only worked once, after that i am getting unauthorized error

Comment: My JS API code, which has been working fine, is throwing 401s today as well, with no changes. I could kill the project and create a new one with a new API key, but I'm not sure that would fix it. I did find that it was "disabled" (due to a billing issue, I think), and I "enabled" it and it still throws 401s.
```
GET https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/info?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.20.0&apikey=THE_CORRECT_API_KEY_HERE

Status 401
Unauthorized
Version HTTP/2
Transferred 586 B (83 B size)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: this problem has vanished today. It appears to have been a bug on the Here side.

---

Yesterday: My JS API code, which has been working fine, is throwing 401s today as well, with no changes. I could kill the project and create a new one with a new API key, but I'm not sure that would fix it. I did find that it was "disabled" (due to a billing issue, I think), and I "enabled" it and it still throws 404s.

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm your email address (by clicking the link in the email they send)?

If you have not confirmed your email address, then the API Key is only valid for 30 minutes.